# create a proper dataframe with an XML file in R

Tags: r, xml

using this worldbank data : 
[GDP CURRENT USD](http://api.worldbank.org/v2/en/indicator/NY.GDP.MKTP.CD?downloadformat=xml)

I would like to create a proper dataframe using `XML` package in Rstudio
The problem I have with the method `xmlToDataFrame` is that it didn't recognize the nodes and show only one observation with 15576 variables...

Regarding other method proposed on stack I didn't manage to create a good data frame with rownames = year and 3 colomn ("Country", "Indicator", "Value")

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Please post a sample of XML in body of question, enough to discern the pattern. Do not rely on us to download a .zip file that will not be available to future readers.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following

```
library(XML)
library(tidyverse)

xml <- xmlParse("API_NY.GDP.MKTP.CD_DS2_en_xml_v2_10475111.xml")
```

### Option 1

```
df <- xml %>%
    getNodeSet("//record") %>%
    map(~setNames(
        rbind.data.frame(xmlSApply(.x, xmlValue), stringsAsFactors = F),
        xmlSApply(.x, xmlGetAttr, "name"))) %>%
    bind_rows()

head(df)
#  Country or Area              Item Year Value
#1           Aruba GDP (current US$) 1960
#2           Aruba GDP (current US$) 1961
#3           Aruba GDP (current US$) 1962
#4           Aruba GDP (current US$) 1963
#5           Aruba GDP (current US$) 1964
#6           Aruba GDP (current US$) 1965
```

We need two `xmlSApply` calls to get the values *and* names separately.

### Option 2

```
colnames <- c("Country", "Item", "Year", "Value")
df <- xml %>%
    getNodeSet("//record") %>%
    xmlToDataFrame() %>%
    setNames(colnames)
head(df)
#  Country              Item Year Value
#1   Aruba GDP (current US$) 1960
#2   Aruba GDP (current US$) 1961
#3   Aruba GDP (current US$) 1962
#4   Aruba GDP (current US$) 1963
#5   Aruba GDP (current US$) 1964
#6   Aruba GDP (current US$) 1965
```

We use `xmlToDataFrame` to coerce the `list` of nodes to a `data.frame`; unfortunately we loose the field names, so we need to add the names as column names in a post-hoc way.

---